Using proxy provider with Scrapy
What is the purpose of the 'CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_IP' setting in Scrapy, and how does it work with 'CONCURRENT_REQUESTS'?
I am using a proxy provider that handles proxy rotation on their side. If I set 'CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_IP' to 10, does it limit the requests to 10 per IP assigned by the proxy provider, or does Scrapy treat the IPs differently?
Thanks!
I've testes scenarios like this:
If my proxy provider supplies 75 IPs, and I configure CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_IP = 5 along with CONCURRENT_REQUESTS = 150, does that mean the global cap of 150 concurrent requests will override the CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_IP setting? Specifically, would Scrapy distribute the requests such that each IP is limited to approximately 2 concurrent requests (150 total ÷ 75 IPs), or would it prioritize reaching the CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_IP limit for each IP until the global cap is hit?

CONCURRENT_REQUESTS defines the maximum number of concurrent (i.e. simultaneous) requests that will be performed by the Scrapy downloader. If you set it to a non-zero number n , no more than n requests can be performed at the same time.
When you perform a request, you must have a target domain or ip, it is like you take a bus and go straight to your target. In case of using a proxy, it is like you take a bus A to a stop, and transfer a bus B to the target.
CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_IP and CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_DOMAIN define the same limitation as CONCURRENT_REQUESTS, but it is used for the ip or domain of target, it is nothing about the transfer (i.e. the proxy you're using, which is the way you get to the target). Changes on these three settings do not affect the proxy (and it's provider). They only affect the target server.
When CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_IP is set to a non-zero number n, CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_DOMAIN is ignored by scrapy.
When CONCURRENT_REQUESTS is set to a non-zero number m and CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_IP or CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_IP is set to a non-zero number n (n<=m), no more than m requests can be performed at the same time totally. If there are multiple targets in your scrapy spider, no more than n requests can be performed at the same time for each target.
